# passing number of type long long into a function (reference vs value) (C++)

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, long-integer

I am new to the use of numbers that aren't doubles or ints. I know that passing an int or double should be passed by value (with consideration to memory/speed) but I am not sure about how to pass the long long data type into a function.

Basically, is a long long number big enough that it would be faster to pass it by a const reference than by value?

Comment: A `double` is usually at least that size.

Comment: Value is best. You should pass most PODs by value. Think of const reference as a way to avoid calling a copy constructor.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that I'm using long long because I need exact values and I've been taught that when dealing with doubles or floats there is actually some chance of errors coming up.

But thank you! I will use pass by value if it is similar to the size of a double.

Comment: If you consider yourself that new, I would suggest to not worry about what could be very small optimizations.

Comment: On 64-bit systems (which are becoming more and more common), `long long` is probably the same size as a pointer anyway.

Comment: You've also been taught that when dealing with int's there is actually some chance of errors coming up. The difference from floats and doubles is that you've been taught what those errors are and how to deal with them. 1/2 is **not** 0, but programmers get comfortable with that notion; too bad they don't get taught to handle floating-point with the same equanimity. (To be fair, floating-point math is more complicated than integer math, but it's not magic, and it's not something to be feared)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is faster or not depends on your compiler and computer architecture. `long long` is not always available on compilers - especially 32-bit compilers.
Generally I would say that you probably won't notice a speed difference, unless you call the function *very* often.

If it is close in size to double or float also depends on your compiler. But the chance of any calculation error is equally big on both `long long` and `double` - only the size of the error differs (if at all).

For what you're describing though - I would say pass by value. Essentially I would recommend pass by reference only if you need to modify the value and you need that change to propagate back to the calling functions - without the need for return values.

Comment: `long long` is a standard type as of C++11. Compilers don't have much choice any more of whether to support it.

Comment: If you compile with C++11... for C or older C++ revisions they don't need to define it. And nothing forces them to really implement C++11. So if that was reason for downvote - I don't understand it.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote for something as trivial and not widely applicable as that.

Comment: Ok - so then someone else, who wouldn't bother to say why, downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a long long number takes 64 bits and the difference is small, it should be just
okay to pass by value.

Generally, for a class or struct, passing by const references is an efficient or a better way, but when the size of the class or structure is small, things become tricky, since references may introduce extra cost of memory addressing and accessing.

Comment: At least 64 bits, though I doubt there's anything different yet.

Comment: @chris, not true, the standard states in §3.9.1 P2: There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long
long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.
There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. The standard and extended signed
integer types are collectively called signed integer types. Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the
architecture of the execution environment44; the other signed integer types are provided to meet special
needs.

Comment: @NathanErnst, It also relies on the C standard for minimum ranges of types, including `long long`, which states that it must support at least a range of [-(2^63-1), 2^63-1].